# Cache all SELECTs with ProxySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, caching, proxysql

I spent a couple of hours setting up ProxySQL to cache all selects, but there is no hit on the query rule. Rule is set up this way:

```
rule_id = 1
active = 1
match_pattern = ^SELECT(.*)$
cache_ttl = 3600000
apply = 1
destination_hostgroup = 36
```

All other variables are NULL or 0, connection thru ProxySQL goes well, rules are loaded into the runtime. I have only one backend server.

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: Remember, `SELECT` is case insensitive. You can also include elements that change over time, like `NOW()`, which are probably bad to cache.

Comment: Well yes, but it is not the point, the question is why the cache has not been hit with this pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Match pattern changed to

```
SELECT .*
```

and it works.

Comment: This is mad. Why even have `.*` at all? Did you figure out why your original expression didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

According to [proxysql's read-write howto](https://github.com/sysown/proxysql/wiki/ProxySQL-Read-Write-Split-(HOWTO)), setting

```
match_pattern = ^SELECT
```

should work.

The `^SELECT` regular expression will match "any query digest starting with SELECT".

Comment: It's worth noting that `match_digest`  matches on the _digest_ of the query (i.e. the query stripped from parameters). `match_pattern` matches on the original query text.